# Does Azure allow to monitor RAM and CPU usage of an on-premises server?

Tags: azure, performance-monitoring

I have an on-premises server and an Azure MSDN account. I heard that Azure supports the concept of a hybrid cloud where some server may be on-premises, not sure if I understand it correctly, though.

For example, I have a few on-premises servers and I wish to have a dashboard with their performance. Basic stuff - CPU and RAM. To be able to configure thresholds and alerts. Can I sort of "on-board" these servers to some kind of Azure Monitoring solution and get all that?

**EDIT 1**

This is what I can see:

[image]

The Save button is disabled. I do not understand how to advance from there.

**EDIT 2**

I could not find the "the big blue button that says “add the selected performance counters”" I can see a small blue button with the + sign, pressing which I get the following:
[image]

**EDIT 3**

So, I gave it to run a few hours, but there is still no data:

[image]

**EDIT 4**

[image]

**EDIT 5**

The heartbeat:

[image]

**EDIT 6**

I followed all the instructions. At the end and after a few days I noticed I have it! Switched to advanced analytics and here I have it:

[image]

Now all I need is a dashboard, better live, but if not the one I can easily refresh.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview

Comment: I followed the instructions and now the server in question has Microsoft Monitoring Agent that is successfully connected to the OMS workspace in my Azure Automation account. But I still do not understand how do I see its CPU and RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is done through OMS/Log analytics. You would install the OMS monitoring agent on the machines you wish to monitor and then connect it to the log analytics workspace you created in Azure. This will hook your machine up to send data to log analytics.

At this point you are not yet sending the data you need, you need to configure Log Analytics to collect perfmon data from the machine. To do this, in the Azure portal select your Log Analytics workspace, then got to "advanced settings", in the window that opens select "data" then "windows performance counters". It will offer you some default counters, this should what you want so i would accept these. Your page should then look like this:

[image]

You will now begin to collect this perfmon data from your machine. Give it a while for some data to be collected, then to view it you can go to the search option in the workspace settings in the portal, and enter a query like

```
Perf | where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total" | summarize AVGCPU = avg(Average) by Computer
```

This will show you data for the average processor time per machine. You can see more details and other queries in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-performance-counters).

---

Edit: You just need to press the button highlighted below to add the default counters.

[image]

Comment: How do you get to this screen? I added what I see on mine to the post and I am stuck there.

Comment: No need to hit the save button, just press the big blue button that says “add the selected performance counters”

Comment: Still no dice. I must be stupid if I am missing something that obvious - please, see my **EDIT 2**.

Comment: @mark See my edit

Comment: I swear the God I was staring at this screen and never saw this button until you highlighted it. Now checking the other steps you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I took your query (there is a typo there), but it returns no results.

Comment: Can you just do a query for "perf" this should show all performon data, does it show anything?

Comment: I feel really stupid, but I cannot run "perf" - see the snapshot I added to the post.

Comment: sorry, it's case sensitive, should be "Perf". Take a look at the link I provided previously, has lots of example queries.

Comment: No results.....

Comment: Ok bare minimum you should get heart beat data from your VM if it is connected to the workspace correctly, can you query for that, see here -https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/examples/Get-latest-heartbeat-record-per-computer-IP if that has not data then your agent isn’t configured to talk to the right workspace or it’s not running

Comment: Seems like there is heartbeat...

Comment: Is there anything else I can check? Because I am at loss here.

Comment: If you're getting heartbeat records from the right machines then they are sending data OK. I would check that the perfmon counters are actually showing as enabled back in Data section. If they are then you may need to raise a support ticket.

Comment: It is quite confusing. Apparently it was a matter of time, plus I need to select the query before clicking Run. But it works! I see the performance counters. Now I need to figure out how to have a real time dashboard.

Comment: Glad it’s working! Best bet for dashboarding is the create the queries your interested in the search page and then pin the graphs you generate to an Azure dashboard.